# Rails belongs_to on join table triggers validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Image and ArData, that are associated through a join table. The Image class `has_one :ar_data_image` and `has_one :ar_data, through: :ar_data_image`. The ArData `has_many :ar_data_images` and `has_many :images, through :ar_data_images`. When I attempt to create an ArData instance and assign `image_ids` to create join records I get a validation error that ar data images is invalid. If I set the `belongs_to :ar_data` in the `ArDataImage` class to `optional: true` it works. It seems like that is a false validation error though since it should create my new model and the join models.

Am I going about this totally incorrectly? I am using Rails 5.1.4 and set `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true`.

Comment: Can you post the error from the logs and the controller code?

Comment: Why do you use a join table if `Image has_one :ar_data`?. Is not enough to define `image belongs_to :ar_data` and `ar_data has_many :images`?

Comment: Originally it was many to many but not anymore